# How to generate OAuth1 headers for Meteor http.get requests

Tags: meteor, oauth

This is probably a simple question, but I am trying to make a server-side API call to a third-party.  Initially, it will be triggered by a client method call, but ultimately will be using setinterval.

I would prefer not to use the accounts-* packages, but will if necessary.  Just struggling with this for some reason.  Can't figure out how to correctly generate the OAuth header.

Comment: I am presuming I need to use the oauth1 package: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/oauth1 so I don't have to build it myself, for whatever reason it's been being obnoxious.  Once I figure it out I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using OAuth1 to call YQL

```
var yqlURL = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';

    var config = {};
    config.consumerKey = 'key';
    config.secret = 'secret';

    var parameters = {};
    parameters.q = 'YQL Query';
    parameters.format = 'json';
    parameters.env = 'store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys';


    // Create OAUTH1 headers to make request to YQL API
    var oauthBinding = new OAuth1Binding(config, yqlURL);

    var yqlResponse = oauthBinding.get(yqlURL, parameters);
```